# How to remove appended graphics command in Createjs?

Tags: easeljs, createjs

Createjs provides an excellent method to append graphics commands.

But what should do if I need to remove those commands, for example, when a shape is clicked?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `clear` method to remove all drawing instructions. Check out the docs: http://createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/Graphics.html#method_clear

Comment: Yeah. I've been using this function. What I'm looking for is a manner of remove a specif command.

Comment: Removing only a specific command isn't possible (wouldn't make that much sense anyway, as the commands are normally depending on each other). You have to rebuild your commands after `clear`.

Comment: Good approach. 

Another one I was think about is to attach those special graphics commands to individuals shapes, as long manipulate them is easy with `removeChild` and `addChild`  functions.